# What is the correct method of reverting a Group Policy Object?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

As I discover the nuances of Group Policy I haved learned that deleting a GPO does not reverse the changes that were effected by a GPO and those changes remain tattooed (a nice description that I read somewhere!) on the registry of the client machine.

The question I have is, if deleting a GPO does not revert its behaviour, does changing a GPO to Disabled then deleting it after clients have updated have an affect on GPO's or local changes that act on the same services post deletion?

The broader question would be, what is the correct way to revert changes made by a GPO?

If my question is too broad and the answer depends on the context of the GPO, a reference to an article discussing the merits of Enabled, Disabled and Not Configured may be enlightening, as I can't find anything I have been able to make sense of.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/607357/gpo-rule-of-thumb-for-disabled-vs-enabled-vs-not-configured/607380#607380) Q&A on ServerFault was quite interesting, but did not quite provide the answers I was looking for.

Comment: Disabled doesn't mean "Not Configured". It means Disabled, for whatever the particular setting is/does. You want to set the setting(s) to Not Configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to either create a new GPO (or reuse the existing) to undo the changes teh first one made.  By setting each option to 'Not Configured' is the easiest.

Comment: Thanks @Skeer. So, Not Configured will always remove any changes that the GPO has made when clients fetch the latest group policy?

Comment: Thats been my experience (10+yrs with AD/GPO)

Comment: Not all settings work this way, such as those defined in Windows Settings\Security Settings.

Comment: If you change a Security Setting from "Defined" to "Not Defined", it simply stops enforcing that configuration, but will not wipe it.